# Enviar archivo por AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Estoy tratando de enviar por `ajax` un archivo por medio de un `input file`, pero el `PHP` me retorna un error.

**¿Cómo se pueden enviar archivos tipo "file" por `ajax`?**

**EL CÓDIGO HTML**

```
<form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo">
    <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**EL CÓDIGO AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
   //// METODO PARA INSERTAR LOS DATOS //// 
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        event.preventDefault();

        var cadena = $(this).serializeArray();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'php.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: cadena
        })      
        .done(function(respuesta) {

            var resultado = $.parseJSON(respuesta);
            console.log(resultado);
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
});
});
```

**EL CÓDIGO PHP**

```
<?php
    $nombre = array($_POST['archivo']);
    echo json_encode($nombre);
?>
```

Comment: quieres enviar el archivo a la base de datos?

Comment: @JuankGlezz, considero que no es un duplicado ya que evidentemente el OP no conoce la [`API FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)

Comment: si..quiero enviar el archivo a la base de datos pero antes de hacerlo necesito la prueba con el ajax ya que si no usuara ajax los archivos compilan de manera correcta pero necesito es enviar ese file por ajax

Comment: que funcionalidad tiene esto? new FormData();  y de que manera podria resolver mi problema?

Comment: Puedes revisar este post en ingles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: ¿Qué error te retorna? Sería más fácil identificar el problema (y la solución) si supieramos el error exacto que recibes. Lee [ask] para información y consejos que te ayudarán a mejorar tus preguntas.

Comment: ¿Qué error te marca? Un pequeño error a simple vista que veo en tu `PHP`, debes cambiar `$_POST['archivo']` por `$_FILES['archivo'];`, luego la etiqueta `form` de tu formulario tampoco está declarado el método `POST` y recuerda que por defecto usara el método `GET`.

Answer (score 3):

Los input de tipo `file` van a la variable `$_FILES`

```
$nombre = $_FILES['file-0'];
```

sobre javascript debes realizar esto

```
var data = new FormData();
jQuery.each($('input[type=file]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file-'+i, file);
});
var other_data = $('form').serializeArray();
$.each(other_data,function(key,input){
    data.append(input.name,input.value);
});
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'php.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: igualmente si retornara ese $_FILES me devuelve un valor vacio

Comment: Hola, ¿al final conseguiste solucionarlo? Tengo exactamente el mismo problema: Cuando realizo en envío del form sin usar ajax obtengo sin problemas los valores del fichero pero si lo hago por ajax nada...

Answer (score 1):

Recomedaria evalues hacer uso del `FormData` para enviar un archivo usando `ajax`

[Ajax File Upload with Form Data using PHP](https://www.codexworld.com/ajax-file-upload-with-form-data-jquery-php-mysql/)

como veras en el ejemplo asigna el `this` al usar

```
 data: new FormData(this),
```

algo como ser

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'submit.php',
        data: new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        .
        .
```